# request.FILES is empty when send ajax file upload request to server

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple form in `index.html`:

```
<div id="Competence-form">
    <form id="competence" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}                    
        <input type="file" id="Picture-text" name="comp-pic" />
        <input type="button" name="comp-defaultButton" value="Default" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is my ajax request in `index.js`:

```
$("#Competence-form").submit(function(event){
    $(".ajaxLogoBoard").show();

    //prevent normal submit when submit button click because check something ...
    event.preventDefault();

    //getting values
    var picture = $("#Picture-text").val();
    var data ={
        picture:picture,
    };

    //send AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/check',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(result){
            // do something
        }
```

In server I want to use `request.FILES` but this dictionary is empty :

```
def competenceCheck(request):
    # ... some code to initialize upload
    # ...
    picture = request.REQUEST['picture']        # this will return the path
    print request.FILES        # but this is empty => <MultiValueDict: {}>
    # ... some code after upload
    # ...
```

where I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload files like that in Ajax - debug logging would show you that `$("#Picture-text").val()` is empty.

You will need to use some sort of file upload plugin to do it.

Comment: More specificity would be helpful here. If another plugin is needed, could you please explain in more detail why? I feel like this should be possible. What are the plugins doing that is so special?

Comment: I'm using the browser's native FileReader api to get the data, which I can see very clearly, but when I send it to the server, request.FILES is still empty.